# SQL Query to find all the superiors of a particular subordinate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursion, common-table-expression

My table contains 3 Columns

```
Emp_ID |  Emp_Name   |  Emp_Manager_ID
========================================
1      |  Admin      |   Null         
2      |  John       |   1            
3      |  Sam        |   2             
4      |  Mike       |   2            
5      |  Jeff       |   4            
6      |  Ben        |   3            
7      |  Vicky      |   5
```

The parameter id @Emp_ID = 7 The expected result to find all the superiors under the given Emp_Id so the result should be all EmpIDs 6,5,4,3,2,1 because 5 is the manager of 7 and 4 is the manager of 5 and 2 is the manager of 4,3 and 3 is the manager of 6 and 1 is the manager of 2.

Answer (score 3):

This works up the tree, and in your case gives 7 -> 5 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 and then stops.

```
WITH
  unrolled_branch AS
(
  SELECT
    emp_id,
    emp_name,
    emp_mnager_id
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
    emp_id = @emp_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    your_table.emp_id,
    your_table.emp_name,
    your_table.emp_mnager_id
  FROM
    yourTable
  INNER JOIN
    unrolled_branch
      ON unrolled_branch.emp_manager_id = yourTable.emp_id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  unrolled_branch
```

I'm stuck on how you also get 3 and 6 though.  Do you just mean that they are of the same level as the others?

You have this tree...

```
1-2-3-6
   \
    4-5-7
```

But what should the results be in this tree?

```
      A-B-C
     /
1-2-3-6
   \
    4-5-7
```

And do you enforce the constraints that any one node may only ever have one parent node, and one node in any tree must have no parent?  Or can either of these be possible?

```
    3   9     5-6     7       C     C
   / \ /         \   /       / \   / \
1-2   6-8         3-4       A   D-A   D- (etc, etc)
   \ /           /   \       \ /   \ /
    4-5-7     1-2     8       B     B
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not displaying 6

Comment: How 3 comes is since 2 is the superior of 4 and 3 it should also take 6 because 3 is the superior of 6

Comment: @MathewPaul - As my answer states, I understand why my code doesn't display 3 and 6.  So I then ask about other scenarios in order to more accurately elaborate your business rules when branching back down the tree.  At present your description *appears* to be asking to "return every single node in the tree" (Climb up every branch, and back down every branch too => reach every node?  Or is there some end condition?)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I think there was a mistake in my part

Comment: Yes the expected result is 5,4,2,1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example:

```
create table #employees (
Emp_ID int,
Emp_Name varchar(10),
Emp_Manager_ID int
)


create table #superiors (
Emp_ID int
)

insert into #employees values (1, 'Admin', NULL)
insert into #employees values (2, 'John', 1)
insert into #employees values (3, 'Sam', 2)
insert into #employees values (4, 'Mike', 2)
insert into #employees values (5, 'Jeff', 4)
insert into #employees values (6, 'Ben', 3)
insert into #employees values (7, 'Vicky', 5)

declare @count int, @testID int
select @testID = 7

select @count = NULL
select @count = Emp_Manager_ID from #employees where Emp_ID = @testID

while(@count IS NOT NULL)
begin
  insert into #superiors values (@count)
  select @count = Emp_Manager_ID from #employees where Emp_ID = @count
end



select * from #superiors


drop table #employees
drop table #superiors
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up a recursive CTE to traverse your hierarchy tree. Have a look at, for example, https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml